# Interface Builder shows old Received Actions

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

When I open my xib file in Interface Builder and click on File's Owner in the Document window, the Connections Inspector is showing far more actions below Received Actions than I have defined in the class as specified by the File's Owner Class Identity.

I have only two IBAction items defined in the class, and both of these actions are shown and hooked up to the appropriate buttons.  I am not sure where these other ones are defined, as when I search the project for the text of the action shown, it is not found anywhere in my project.  (I believe that the actions shown are from a previous software application that I did on this same computer.)

I cannot find any way to get rid of these, and while the application still works as it should, I would like to try to find a way to get these actions out of there.

I am using the most recently released iOS SDK 4.1.

Comment: what are they? some are built into certain types of classes that you might be subclassing.

Comment: The actions listed are like timePressed: and distancePressed:, which are actions that I used in another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to just edit the xib file by hand and remove the invalid actions.

Comment: I found the bad actions in an extra <object class="IBPartialClassDescription"> entry in the xib file, not sure how it got there or how I could have removed them from the interface of Interface Builder.  But it the extra entries are gone now, thanks.